# Is it correct to use a term 'forever' to emphasize how long a situation was taking place?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

I would like to write something like:

> We were talking about our cultural similarities and differences forever

to indicate that we were doing it for a very long period of time. Is that correct? Can it be used in a formal letter? And can Past Simple be used or is only the Past Continuous correct?

Comment: The usage of *forever* to mean 'a long period of time'  seems to be colloquial, and is okay in informal, slangy speech but its appropriateness probably diminishes the more formal a context becomes. You can use either the past simple or past continuous with 'a long period of time'  and the would apply to using 'forever'  with that meaning. But  again, it comes across as kind of slangy to me, so not everybody is going to use it that way in even ordinary everyday language.

Comment: 'We were forever talking about our cultural similarities and differences.' means 'on numerous occasions'. 'His lecture on particle physics went on for ever.' is hyperbole, meaning 'for far too long [in my opinion]'. Your example sounds unidiomatic.

Comment: The difference between simple past and past continuous has surely been covered in other questions.  Take a good look.  You may find something more helpful on ELL SE. // This use of "forever" would be best left to native or near-native speakers.  It's a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best not to use "forever" in this way in a formal letter.
As a completed act, better this:

> We spoke at length about our cultural similarities and differences .

If the activity is continuing, maybe this:

> We have been speaking at length about our cultural similarities and differences.

If the original tense is desired, this:

> We were speaking at length about our cultural similarities and differences.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing *grammatically* wrong with it.  You would say "We were talking about our cultural similarities and differences for 18 minutes and 43 seconds", wouldn't you?

There is a question of whether such hyperbole is appropriate in a given situation, but that is not a grammatical question.

Comment: Yeah, folks have been using that form, like, forever.  But in a formal context I'd use "interminabubububly".